# libusb_get_device_list seg fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, libusb

I am writing a file explorer application in Qt C++ and have a libUSB function (QList UsbDevice::getDeviceList()) which gets all attached USB devices, checks each one for my products vendor and product ID's, claims them and the returns them in an array. This all works fine and I get the device I want, however I have added a refresh button which should update the device list shown in a drop-down list (it basically calls the getDeviceList function again) but it seg faults when calling:

```
int numDevices = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &usbDevices);
```

the second time around and I can't for the life of me see why. If someone could check over the code below and see if I have missed something stupid that would be very helpful.

```
QList<UsbDevice*> UsbDevice::getDeviceList()
{

unsigned char manf[256] = {'\0'};

QList<UsbDevice*> usbDeviceList;

libusb_device **usbDevices;
struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;

int numDevices = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &usbDevices);
if(numDevices < 0)
{
    libusb_free_device_list(usbDevices, 1);
    return usbDeviceList;
}
QString error;

for(int i=0; i!=numDevices; ++i)
{
    libusb_device *dev = usbDevices[i];
    libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);

    if((desc.idVendor != VendorUsbId) && (desc.idProduct != ProductUsbId))
        continue;

    libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
    libusb_config_descriptor *conf_desc = NULL;

    int result = 0;

    result = libusb_open(dev, &handle);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        if(result == -3)
        {

        }
        error = QString(libusb_error_name(result));
        continue;
    }

    int config = 1;



    if( handle == NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }

    result = libusb_set_configuration(handle, config);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        error = QString(libusb_error_name(result));
        continue;
    }

    result = libusb_get_config_descriptor(dev, 0, &conf_desc);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        error = QString(libusb_error_name(result));
        continue;
    }

    result = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        error = QString(libusb_error_name(result));
        continue;
    }

    result = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, manf, sizeof(manf));
    if(result < 0)
    {
        error = QString(libusb_error_name(result));
        continue;
    }

    UsbDevice *newDevice = new UsbDevice();
    newDevice->setDeviceName(QString((char*)manf));
    newDevice->setHandle(handle);

    usbDeviceList << newDevice;
}

libusb_free_device_list(usbDevices, 1);

return usbDeviceList;

}
```

Comment: Could it be possible that you have called `libusb_exit()` after the first time, and not called `libusb_init()` before the second time ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I call them at the very beginning and very end of the program like so:                                      #include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <libusb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    struct libusb_context *context;

    if( libusb_init(&context) < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    libusb_exit(context);

    return a.exec();
} should it be done every time the function is called? i was under the impression that multiple inits caused an issue?

Comment: You should edit your question to add code, as it is not very readable in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `libusb_init()` at the beginning of your program, but you are also calling `libusb_exit()` at the beginning : before calling `a.exec()`.

Your first call probably happens in `MainWindow` constructor ?

You could instead subclass `QApplication`, call `libusb_init()` in the constructor and `libusb_exit()` in the destructor.

Comment: Lol yes that would have been a better way to deal with the extra info in my comment, I will remember for my next post. Thanks for your suggestion, I have implemented the change and it now works! :)

Comment: @user3130167 If this solution works, you should accept the answer